# How to improve "nt.stat" and "getmodule" performance in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, profiling

I am running a python script using a local packakge folder on my computer. It is significantly slow. I tried to profile it use the "cProfile". Below is the result

```
    27163509262 function calls (26876957168 primitive calls) in 45242.287 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 62862676 9841.903    0.000 9841.904    0.000 {built-in method nt.stat}
 23360775 1778.411    0.000 4344.513    0.000 mypath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\inspect.py:850(getmodule)
-1833258512/-1833258536 1667.529   -0.000 2230.835   -0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
 42865521 1168.789    0.000 1373.451    0.000 mypath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py:468(maybe_promote)
-1058433517 1035.505   -0.000 1065.701   -0.000 {built-in method builtins.hasattr}
515005085  967.796    0.000 4666.300    0.000 mypath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:943(__getitem__)
-1322991622  676.388   -0.000  908.008   -0.000 mypath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\inspect.py:182(ismodule)
515005085  542.937    0.000 2657.906    0.000 mypath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1052(_get_value)
 23960548  479.766    0.000  646.542    0.000 {pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_objects}
562604434  475.813    0.000 1652.195    0.000 mypath\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3577(get_loc)
  3364611  475.311    0.000  475.311    0.000 {pandas._libs.tslibs.vectorized.ints_to_pydatetime}
  ...
```

The first two functions above are "nt.stat" and "getmodule" cost me 33% of the time. What are they and how can I improve them?

Comment: See https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-standard-library/0596000960/ch12s12.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule. Without seeing the code, it will be hard to suggest improvements.